# Same string for custom page type and slug

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom post type `team` and a page titled "Team" whose slug is also `team`.

Team page is assigned to `page-team.php` (template name "Team"). `team` custom post type uses `single-team.php` template file. When my browser points to `/team` it uses the `index.php` template instead of the page I wanted (the team page file).

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wordpress Codex: Post Types section URLs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types):

> The new post type will also get its own special section of the site layout. In the above example, posts of this new "product" type can be displayed at http://example.com/product/%product_name% (where %product_name% is the URL-ized name of your product, i.e. http://example.com/product/foobrozinator.) You can see this link appear in the edit pages for your new type, just like other posts.

This means:

1. Your custom type **team** pages are all reachable under http://example.com/team/%slug%.
2. Since your slug is **team** the url is http://example.com/team/team.

Makes sense. The Codex page about custom post type is worth a good and thorough read.

**Edit**: If you aren't happy with `/team/team`, try the [Custom post type permalink](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) plugin.